# react-intl onChange testing using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a drop down button component in my react app that lets me change my language

My localeDropDown.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

const propTypes = {
  locale: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

class LocaleDropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {value: ''}
    this.handleLocaleChange = this.handleLocaleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleLocaleChange (e) {
    Cookie.set('locale', e.target.value)
    window.location.reload()
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({inputValue: Cookie.get('locale')})
  }

  render () {
    return <div>
      <select id="locale-value" onChange={this.handleLocaleChange} value={this.state.inputValue}>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  }
}

LocaleDropDown.propTypes = propTypes

export default LocaleDropDown
```

and my tests are

```
      const handleLocaleChange = sinon.spy();
      const wrapper = shallow(<LocaleDropDown onChange = {handleLocaleChange}/>)
      const selectInput = wrapper.find("#locale-value")
      selectInput.node.value = 'en'
      wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', selectInput);
      expect(handleLocaleChange.called).toEqual(true)
```

But it gives me error 
LocaleDropDown › when simulating a change, handleLocaleChange should be called

```
TypeError: Cannot add property value, object is not extensible
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A [mock event object can be passed along to simulate an event](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) like so:

```
wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'en' } })
```

More details about the method signature:

> .simulate(event[, ...args]) => Self
>
> Simulate events
>
> **Arguments**
>
> event (String): The event name to be simulated
>
> ...args (Any [optional]): A mock event object that will get passed through to the event handlers.

Comment: React prevents from making modifications to children. You will need to either pass down an initial locale as props or remove `selectInput.node.value = 'en'`